# Too much oil in engine

Tags: engine, oil, mercedes-benz

If I've accidentally poured more oil than necessary, how much would a job to fix this error usually cost?

Comment: We don't do costs on here as they vary by country / region etc too much.

Comment: very true. Was jus trying to get a ballpark to measure the amount of labor that goes into solving this issue. Measuring comparison from a simple oil change to a job like replacing transmission. Big vs small

Comment: Change your oil.  Done.  A side-effect of changing your oil is resetting the amount of oil in the engine.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider one of those suction pumps with a tube that goes down the dipstick tube ...

How much is too much? If you are just over the max mark and driving on level ground it may be fine, but if you have added 10litres instead of 5 then you need to do something and not start the engine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Probably like 2L more. I've driven it approximately 10 miles already

Comment: For my first oil change i put 1/2 QT extra, and got a cheap plastic tube for a few bucks. I just put it in the fill hole and sucked the oil **HALF** way up the tube, remove the tube holding the end and let it drain out in a bottle. Repeated a couple of times.